# Bash. Redirecting output of grep into file

Tags: bash, shell, directory

I have a basic bash script that i want to use to create a list of directories inside a file. The issue is that when i type the following command on the terminal it works fine but when used inside a function it does not

```
function Create_file_dirs()
{ 
    ls | grep / > dirs.txt
    cat dirs.txt #used for debugging
}
```

This function is inside a script and i'm running it by calling the script. ./script.sh

`

The command 
    `ls | grep / > dirs.txt` 
works great on the terminal window and produces a file listing directories line by line, but doesn't do anything when used inside a function and i can't figure out why. Thanks

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: In the interactive prompt, `ls` is probably an alias for `ls -F`.  Try just using `ls -F | grep ...`

Comment: As an aside -- `Create_file_dirs() { set -- */; { [[ -d $1 ]] && printf '%q\n' "$@"; } >dirs.txt; }` is a way to write this that doesn't require `ls` (or other commands external to the shell itself) at all, and will write hidden characters in your filenames in a way that's clear to the reader. (The `function` keyword does nothing but make your code less portable; don't use it).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Clever one-liner, but maybe a bit difficult to decipher for many users?

Comment: @Fred, *shrug*. It's only a one-liner because I was writing it into a comment field. Replace the `;`s with newlines if you think it's too terse. `ls` is [objectively a bad tool](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for any use case other than listings for purely human consumption -- if you wanted something that uses less-obscure behavior and were willing to eat the performance cost of starting a process external to the shell, the better alternative would be `find`.

Comment: @Fred, ...OTOH, I'd argue that rather than *avoiding* syntax because it's too obscure, the better approach is to teach it, and thereby make it *less* obscure. Doubly so when that syntax has correctness and portability benefits. (Not to mention other practical value: If you need to do maintenance/troubleshooting on a machine with a dead `/lib` directory where you only have shell builtins working, knowing how to use those builtins effectively is a lifesaver).

Comment: My comment was not about how "compact" your solution was, but it would need some explanations to the average shell user to show how and why it works (I had to look at it for a bit to figure it out).  Quick question : do you think  "for A in */ ; do printf "%q\n" "$A" ; done" would yield the same result (forget it, no it would not)?

Comment: @Fred, the only place where it wouldn't yield the same result is if there *are* no subdirectories (and the `nullglob` option is off, as is default); that's the case the `[[ -d $1 ]]` is meant to handle. If you didn't need to handle that, you could just `printf '%q\n' */` (or, if you don't want to shell-escape names, ie. `printf '%s\n' */`, but that's hazardous with newline-delimited output; the directory created with `mkdir $'foo\nbar\nbaz'`, for instance, will show up on three separate lines -- which is why for non-human consumption, NUL delimiters are the way to go).

Comment: I know, right after I wrote that comment I checked the empty directory case and saw it dit not work, hence the edit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` without options does not produce slashes, so grep doesn't find anything. You can easily reproduce it on the command line by, say,

```
comand ls|grep /
```

Answer (score 1):

My thanks to William Pursell for his answer and to everyone who contributed.

The answer came from a comment made by William Pursell. 
The working function is:

```
    create_file_dirs()
{ 
    ls -F | grep / >./dirs.txt
    cat dirs.txt
}
```

The issue was,that when i was running the ls command on the terminal i could see a slash / after a directories name and running the command on the terminal actually produced the desired result.

```
ls | grep / > ./dirs.txt
```

It seems though running ls through a script doesn't produce a slash / after a directories name that is why i had to add them -F option to resolve this issue.

The way i tested it out was with this simple function inside a script and run the script. The result didn't have slashes.

```
test_dirs(){
    ls | cat
}
```